# SQLite addData cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm just starting to learn to program and am trying to write an Android app with an SQLite database.  I'm running into a compilation error that I don't really understand how to fix.

When trying to run the app I get the following error:

```
error: method addData in class DatabaseHelper cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String,String,String,String,String
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here is the code for the Database Helper:

```
package com.tt.www.ca2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CannApicius1";

public static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

public static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "Users";
public static final String USERID = "UserID";
public static final String USERNAME = "UserName";
public static final String NAME1 = "FirstName";
public static final String NAME2 = "LastName";
public static final String COMPANYNAME = "Company";
public static final String USEREMAIL = "EmailAddress";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "create table " + TABLE_NAME1 + "(USERID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME Text, NAME1 Text, NAME2 Text, COMPANYNAME Text, USEREMAIL Text)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME1);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String UserID, String UserName, String FirstName, String LastName, String Company, String EmailAddress) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(USERID,UserID);
    contentValues.put(USERNAME,UserName);
    contentValues.put(NAME1,FirstName);
    contentValues.put(NAME2,LastName);
    contentValues.put(COMPANYNAME, Company);
    contentValues.put(USEREMAIL,EmailAddress);
    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding" + UserID + " to " + TABLE_NAME1);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

}

Here is the java code for the activity in which the data I'm trying to save is entered:

```
package com.tt.www.ca2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EditUserInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
TextView seeUserID;
EditText editUsername,editFirstName,editLastName,editCompanyName,editEmail;
ImageButton btnsaveuserdata;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_user_info);
    seeUserID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userIDview);
    editUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    editFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
    editLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2);
    editCompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.companyname);
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);
    btnsaveuserdata = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.savesettingsbtn);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    btnsaveuserdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newEntry = seeUserID.getText().toString();
            editUsername.getText().toString();
            editFirstName.getText().toString();
            editLastName.getText().toString();
            editLastName.getText().toString();
            editCompanyName.getText().toString();
            editEmail.getText().toString();
        if (editUsername.length() != 0) {
            AddData(newEntry);
            editUsername.setText("");
        } else {
            toastMessage("You must put something in the username field");
        }
        }
    });
}

public void AddData(String newEntry) {
    boolean insertData = myDb.addData(newEntry);
    if (insertData) {
        toastMessage("Data Inserted Successfully");
    }   else    {
        toastMessage("Something Went Wrong!");
    }

}

private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

The code editor identifies the line "boolean insertData = myDb.addData(newEntry);" as the

source of the error, but I'm struggling to figure out how to get mbDb to find all of the data strings.

[image]

Comment: `myDb.addData(newEntry)` is missing several arguments... There are two different methods... `addData` (for the database) and `AddData` (from the Activity)

Comment: What is not clear? your method addData requires 6 Strings arguments and you call it with only one AddData(newEntry);

Comment: You should assign `editUsername.getText().toString()` to a variable... You then need to give that variable to the database to insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addData()` Function In `DatabaseHelper.java` Takes 6 String Type Arguments As Shown Below

```
 public boolean addData(String UserID, String UserName, String FirstName, String LastName, String Company, String EmailAddress)/*<-Over Here*/ {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(USERID,UserID);
        contentValues.put(USERNAME,UserName);
        contentValues.put(NAME1,FirstName);
        contentValues.put(NAME2,LastName);
        contentValues.put(COMPANYNAME, Company);
        contentValues.put(USEREMAIL,EmailAddress);
        Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding" + UserID + " to " + TABLE_NAME1);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

But when you are calling that(`addData()`) function on `EditUserInfo.java` You Are Passing Only 1 Argument Shown Below:-

```
public void AddData(String newEntry) {
    boolean insertData = myDb.addData(newEntry);/*<-Over Here*/
    if (insertData) {
        toastMessage("Data Inserted Successfully");
    }   else    {
        toastMessage("Something Went Wrong!");
    }

}
```

**Solution:-**

**`AddData():-`**

You Need To Add More Arguments Like This:-

```
public void AddData(String userId, String username, String name1, String name2, String companyName, String userEmail) {
    boolean insertData = myDb.addData(userId,username,name1,name2,companyName,userEmail);
    if (insertData) {
        toastMessage("Data Inserted Successfully");
    }   else    {
        toastMessage("Something Went Wrong!");
    }

}
```

**`onCreate()`**:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_user_info);
    seeUserID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userIDview);
    editUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    editFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
    editLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2);
    editCompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.companyname);
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);
    btnsaveuserdata = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.savesettingsbtn);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    btnsaveuserdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String userId= seeUserID.getText().toString();
            String username = editUsername.getText().toString();
            String name1 = editFirstName.getText().toString();
            String name2 = editLastName.getText().toString();
            String companyName = editCompanyName.getText().toString();
            String userEmail = editEmail.getText().toString();
        if (editUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            AddData(userId,username,name1,name2,companyName,userEmail);
            editUsername.setText("");
        } else {
            toastMessage("You must put something in the username field");
        }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I couldn't figure out where I was supposed to be adding the other strings.  That did the trick.